# Upgrading custom events to Global Site Tag - In Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, gtag.js

I have a functioning script that is working, but I want to use 'Global Site Tag' instead of the old 'I,S,O,G,R,A,M' scripts.

Is there any way to make this script send events, using this new gtag instead:

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXXX-1"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXX-1');
</script>
```

Implemented into this event-firing script, seen here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-124172105-36', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery("a[href^='tel']").on('click', function (){
      ga('send', 'event', 'mobil_opkald', 'klik');
  }); 
}); 
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery("a[href^='mailto']").on('click', function (){
      ga('send', 'event', 'henvendelse', 'klik');
  });
});
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery("a[href^='google']").on('click', function (){
      ga('send', 'event', 'google_maps', 'klik');
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use this syntax to send an event with **gtag**:

```
gtag('event', <action>, {
  'event_category': <category>,
  'event_label': <label>,
  'value': <value>
});
```

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/events

For example, you can send your last event you indicated in your post in this way (I am assuming that the click is set correctly ie that it performs the function):

```
jQuery("a[href^='google']").on('click', function (){
    gtag('event', 'klik', {
      'event_category': 'google_maps'
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, greatly appreciate it!

My jquery wont fire events. can you help me with an example of how to implement the new syntax - for one of my functions?